# How to display uncompressed gray video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-playback, video-codecs

I have video file that is capture of uncompressed video stream. Its media info is as follows:

- Format                                   : AVI
- Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
- Format profile                           : OpenDML
- File size                                : 21.5 GiB
- Duration                                 : 11mn 44s
- Overall bit rate                         : 262 Mbps
- Video ID                                 : 0
- Format                                   : YUV
- Codec ID                                 : GREY
- Codec ID/Info                            : Simple grayscale video
- Duration                                 :   11mn 44s
- Bit rate                                 : 262 Mbps
- Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
- Height                                   : 1 024 pixels
- Display aspect ratio                     : 5:4
- Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
- Color space                              : YUV
- Compression mode                         : Lossless
- Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 8.000
- Stream size                              : 21.5 GiB (100%)

Ths should be the most simple video to display, but not a single one of my players can do that, for some reason. How do i work with it?

Edit: here is command line output of ffmpeg conversion command:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmt grey -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4

ffmpeg version N-55966-gfdd1aaf Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep  2 2013 18:01:19 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 43.100 / 52. 43.100
  libavcodec     55. 31.100 / 55. 31.100
  libavformat    55. 15.100 / 55. 15.100
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 82.102 /  3. 82.102
  libswscale      2.  5.100 /  2.  5.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
Option pixel_format not found.
```

This is output for just probing the file (ffmpeg -i input.avi):

```
[avi @ 02a7b5c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none (GREY / 0x59455247), 1280x1024): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
i:/sun2M.avi: could not find codec parameters
```

Comment: Can ffmpeg read the video on its own, i.e. if you leave out `-pix_fmt grey` altogether?

Comment: No, it fails to do so as well.

Comment: Hm. It seems the AVI was incorrectly written and does not declare the right codec to use – ideally ffmpeg should show it as `rawvideo`. No way to get the file in a different format, I presume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "unknown codec" message indicates that it cannot determine the codec used by the input file.  Therefore, specify the input codec on the command line (`rawvideo` in this case).  To convert to 4:2:0 H.264:

```
ffmpeg -c:v rawvideo -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Comment: this worked just fine